# AWS: How do I restrict deployment to ECS clusters using IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have multiple Fargate clusters in a single AWS account.  I wish to ensure that a given service account (used by the build pipeline) can only update Services within a given Fargate clusters.

The IAM policy editor prompt for the `ecs:UpdateService` action's resource is `arn:aws:ecs::<aws_account_id>:service/` which doesn't make sense given that different clusters can have Services that share a name.  **`aws ecs describe-tasks`** shows both a "clusterArn" and "serviceArn" for each task.  **`aws ecs list-services`** and **`aws ecs describe-services`** only apply to Services for a given cluster.

Answer (score 2):

I created a policy that restricts the `ecs:UpdateService` action to only be able to update the `arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<aws_account_id>:<service>` resource, with a "StringEquals" [condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html) specifying a `ecs:cluster` condition key set to the ARN of the ECS cluster.  Using this method, you could give `*` for `<service>` to allow a policy to update all services in a given cluster.

Documentation: [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon Elastic Container Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonelasticcontainerservice.html)